# Lexical Binding with Task and FrameworkElement parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm getting what I expect from the following statement in terms of the parameters of the outer lambda being available inside the Task but, some of the properties of the FrameworkElement cast object, including Name, throw a System.InvalidOperationException. No such error in the outer lambda.

```
Targets.AddHandler(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent, 
    (ExecutedRoutedEventHandler) ((s,e) => 
        Task.Run(() => 
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Targets {0} {1}", 
            ((FrameworkElement)s).Name, e.RoutedEvent.Name)))) 
    , true);
```

Here is a section of the watch for `((FrameworkElement)s).Name` Inside the Task...

[image]

I guess this is a threading issue?
What is the reason for the errors and what is the best way to pass the values I need into the Task?

---

### Solution

As explained by @Mercer, I need to take care of the thread affinity of the `DependencyObject`.  As stated in the answer, it inherits from `DispatcherObject` and so - just for completeness for the sake of the question - I could exploit that to the full to get a live value of the property if it were necessary.

```
Targets.AddHandler(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent,
    (ExecutedRoutedEventHandler) (async (s, e) =>
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var source = s as FrameworkElement;
                string elementName = "null";
                source.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    elementName = source.Name
                );

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Targets {0} {1}",
                    elementName, e.RoutedEvent.Name));
            })
    )
    , true
);
```

Regarding my question in the comments below, based on the suggested reading, I guess the reason that it is a good idea await a Task is to to do with thread life cycle.
I tried the async version above, with a Thread.Sleep call in the Task and compared it to the same thing with async and await deleted. It performed identically. The window containing the above code is launched from a main window and if I initiated the task and closed the child window, leaving the main window running, the MessageBox would still show after the Sleep period.  If I closed the host window as well, before the Task completed, the process terminated and the MessageBox didn't show.
I don't know if there are any memory leaks in either case but I assume that the practice of awaiting the task is to eliminate that risk.

Comment: Calling `MessageBox.Show` in a new Task doesn't make sense. It should be called in the UI thread. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Besides that, you could write an async event handler as `async (s, e) => await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: I just don't want the message box to be modal. What do you mean? Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: As said, it should be called in the UI thread, not in any background thread like the one where the Task runs.

Comment: Why do you suggest the async await? If I understand it correctly, all it does is call back to return. How does that help?

Comment: You're running a Task without awaiting it. This should generally be avoided. Always await a Task.

Comment: Ok, care to elaborate, cite knowledge sources? 1. What a re the consequences of not waiting a task. 2. How to do non-modal message box?

Comment: Take a look at MSDN, google async/await. Read Stephen Cleary's blog posts.

Comment: Calling `MessageBox.Show` in another thread seems to be safe. However, in that thread you can't access any dependency properties of UI elements that were created in your application's UI thread.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  By the way, Stephen Cleary has a tip saying that it's better to avoid await for simple asynchronous functions. So I'm still confused about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a background thread, like the one that the Task runs in, you can't access dependency properties of DependencyObjects that were created in the application's UI thread. This is because DependencyObjects are DispatcherObjects and therefore have thread affinity.

A simple example with a Button Click handler:

```
<Button Content="Click" Click="OnButtonClick"/>
```

The following Click handler method throws an InvalidOperationException:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    await Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show((string)button.Content));
}
```

While this one will not:

```
private async void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var content = (string)button.Content;
    await Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show(content));
}
```

I guess in your scenario it is also ok not to await the Task:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var content = (string)button.Content;
    Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show(content));
}
```